# Cors issue across domains

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cors

We have a very badly written legacy WebSite application that we are trying to slowly convert to MVC.

As part of this we will be creating a set of MVC controllers that we would like to be able to call from the legacy website as a stopgap measure.

So far I have the following in the website aspx page as an event on the click of a button;

```
function CallControllerMethod() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost:49443/Home/TestAjaxMethod",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
}
```

And this calls a controller method in the MVC project;

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableCors("*","*","*")]
    public int TestAjaxMethod()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

In the WebApiConfig in the MVC app I have this;

```
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    configuration.EnableCors(cors);
```

So when i call the controller method from the website, my breakpoint in the mvc controller is hit.  However, when I return the value of 10, on the website ajax call I get the following error;

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:49443/Home/TestAjaxMethod. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:49252' is therefore not allowed access.

What's confusing is that the Ajax call makes it to the controllers method but I can't seem to return the value from it.

**Update**

Even if I remove all references to Cors from the WebApiConfig and from the controller, the MVC method is still reached and I get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried changing return type for example to `JsonResult` and return code to `return Json(new { Result = 10 });` ?

Comment: I was returning json but i had the same error so i tried to make the test as simple as possible

Comment: Webapi attributes has no impact on mvc controllers.

Comment: Right, I kinda noticed :)  So what does?

Comment: Any reason you can't use webapi controllers?

Comment: What web server are you using? IIS?

Comment: @garethb, I guess not.  What I was hoping for was a way to move forward using standard controllers and then when we switch over we wouldn't need to rewrite anything

Comment: @SimplyGed, yes IIS

Comment: @griegs Then perhaps add a layer behind the controllers that handles everything, so your webapi controllers (and eventually mvc controllers) can just call the methods in this layer. So to move from webapi to mvc, you only require adding a few lines. This will also leave open the option of using a front end framework like Angular if you leave the webapi and not remove it when the controllers are added.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, the `EnableCors` attribute only applies to WebAPI controllers. If you want to add a CORS header to a regular MVC method, you could do it manually.

For example here is some code I've used in the past:

```
var origin = Request.Headers["Origin"];

if (origin != null)
{
    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
}
```

Alternatively, you can create your own attribute:

```
public class AddCorsHeader : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> origin;
        if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("Origin", out origin))
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
        }
    }
}
```

and then add `[AddCorsHeader]` to the relevant methods.